# How do I Send Linkedin Friend Requests via 3rd Party App?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a way for a 3rd party app to do requests such as: POST friend/requests GET friend/request data?
What are the limitations per request are they based on the user or the app and which period of time is the limit set to?

Answer (score 0):

You must be approved by linked in to do this. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context) should make it a little clearer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Invitation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/invitations). To access this API you have to be enroll in partner program.